# SAM3X8E Maximum Serial Speed

Tags: serial, usb, sam3x

Does somebody know which is the maximum serial speed one can achieve by using the Microchip SAM3X8E microprocessor with Serial Communication between other uC with a RS485 module?

The Arduino Due seems to be limited up to 115kbps, the USB (UOTGHS) should reach 1.5Mbps (low speed) without trouble, but I am not sure about the UART

From [Microchip SAM3X8E Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf) section 34.5.1 Baud Rate Generator, the UART baud rate should be the Master Clock MCK divided by 16, the maximum value given by setting the clock divisor UART_BRGR to 1, the minimum value after 0 (UART disabled).

Hence the Master Clock MCK should be around 84MHz (its Maximum Possible Clock?), and then the Maximum Baud Rate should be 5.25Mbps?

Is this right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quoting: "The maximum allowable baud rate is Master Clock divided by 16." from the SAM3X8 datasheet... However the maximum speed of RS485 bus transciever would be probably main bottleneck...

Comment: @KIIV Hence which is the MCK maximum value? Should it be 84MHz and then the maximum UART datarate should be 5.25Mbps?